# Understanding a Box plot

Tags: visualization, outlier

I have a dataset and I have tried plotting it in a box plot after loading the csv in usings pandas. The plot itself is given below.

[image: Box Plot with 6 features and 1 output y]

I need to understand why the `x1` feature doesn't have a lower whisker and what is represented by solid blue bar after the top whisker of the `x1` feature.

Please help with this so that I may decide whether I need to look into outliers removal for feature `x1`.

Comment: Did you read wikipedia??

Answer (score 2):

The solid blue bar above the top whisker are your outliers. If you dont want them, you could pass showfliers=False as an argument.

And for the lower whisker, you may want to adjust the y-scaling of your boxplt.

Hope it helps.